# django mysql syncdb doesn't create tables in models.py

Tags: mysql, django

I have a server using django. I'm trying to switch my database from sqlite3 to mysql. Everything worked fine with sqlite3 before. However, when I use mysql and do

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I didn't get any error, but the tables specified in models.py are not created. Only the following tables are created:

```
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-0F-D2-F3 prototype]$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table south_migrationhistory
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: See the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27204663

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using South.  Normally South would inhibit the creation of most tables in the syncdb, and you'd be expected to run your South migrations to create them for the first time.  This is so South can keep track of the state of your tables and apply any special migration rules you have, even initially.

The other possibility is that you don't have all of your apps listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in the settings file.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It was because of South. I reset the south database and then did a syncdb again. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have south installed.

When you run `python manage.py syncdb` it syncs all the non-south managed apps.

run `python manage.py migrate` to sync the other apps.

this is a tutorial I ran some of my coworkers through (the official south docs are more in depth, I had 15 minutes to get them on south and productive): https://gist.github.com/fyaconiello/2423447

Comment: Yeah this is the problem. I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be also the case that you inherited your  model class from object and not from models.Model

The table will not be created. And no error will be raised

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution:

1. create another database, for example db2
2. change your `DATABASES['default']` in settings point to this db
3. for the latest Django version just run python manage.py migrate

This will create new and clear db structure

4. You need to move needed tables, for mysql: `ALTER table db1.table_name RENAME db2.table_name`

Thats all, thanks